# How to get my idea working?

Tags: professionalism, work-experience, startup, freelancing, fresher

I have an Idea in my mind which I think could make a big hit if become real. The problem I am facing is, I am not a good programmer and I couldn't get this working by myself. But the good part here is, I have my best friends who are neither that pro but who could build this is a descent manner. But they are not that impressed with my idea as I am. They told me they will help me to work this out but not working anything on that. What should I do next?? How can I get along with my Idea??

Comment: Voting to close because this question appears to be off-topic - it has nothing to do with navigating the workplace.

Comment: This might be on topic at startups.SE...

Comment: If your idea is truly a money maker, then you need to create a business plan and search for venture capital funding.  If you want to make money you have to be a businessperson and think in terms of marketing and budgets and all that boring stuff. Programming is the easiest part to get done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1- Seek professional help

Look for people/company/freelancers that creates your idea for a sum of fee.

- Pros: Professional quality(hopefully), allowing you to focus more on the creative side of your idea.
- Cons: Having to pay.

### 2- Continue on development with your friends

- Pros: Not having to pay, or maybe paying less? or even paying later when the idea proves to be a success.
- Cons: Lack of motivation, because you say that they are not that impressed with your idea as you are. Lower quality program unless your friends are experienced developers.

### 3- D.I.Y.

- Pros: In total control of your idea, not having to pay a single cent.
- Cons: Too much to bear for any one person to learn all different aspects in development, unless you already have the experience.
  Still not recommended even if you do have the experience.

## Do Not:

- Be afraid to share your idea with people you know. Different people will have different opinion, some to discourage you, calling your idea stupid or saying no way that would work but sometimes, good comments allowing you to know the weakness of your idea and you could improve on it.
- Be afraid that people will steal your idea. The important thing is to complete at least a working prototype and be able to show your idea.

How much is an idea worth?
A dime a dozen or around $0.00833333333 each.

Get it done! Good luck.

Comment: Is freelancing a good option to develop from scratch?? Isn't there a chance for that freelancer to develop something similar after developing that to me??

Comment: I mostly agree but the last thing a half-baked idea needs is paid professional help. Much better to convince friends and associates to become a part of it-- if they're not interested, that's an important data point in itself.